# How write a query on item in a collection in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my problem.
I have documents with many states and I'm looking for some state at a define time. Sample :

```
      {
        "_index" : "toto-2022",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "9eba6fbbe4284f9d92ad183f5a4bab43",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "conversationId" : "9eba6fbbe4284f9d92ad183f5a4bab43",
          "@timestamp" : "2022-11-10T14:17:53.372+0100",
          "etats" : [
            {
              "date" : "2022-11-09T12:32:30.091+0100",
              "niveauVisibilite" : 1,
              "etat" : "ROUTEE",
              "commentaire" : "Routée",
              "rang" : 1
            },
            {
              "date" : "2022-11-10T07:07:55.351+0100",
              "niveauVisibilite" : 1,
              "etat" : "TERMINEE",
              "commentaire" : "Terminée",
              "rang" : 2
            }
          ]
         }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "toto-2022",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "476ffa93b550497da26380348d97e199",
        "etats" : [
            {
              "date" : "2022-11-10T08:03:17.869+0100",
              "niveauVisibilite" : 1,
              "etat" : "ROUTEE",
              "commentaire" : "Routée",
              "rang" : 1
            },
            {
              "date" : "2022-11-10T07:05:23.669+0100",
              "niveauVisibilite" : 1,
              "etat" : "TERMINEE",
              "commentaire" : "Terminée",
              "rang" : 2
            }
          ]
        }
```

I only want to have the document with the status ROUTEE on the 11-09-2022.

My query is

```
 GET /toto-2022/_search
 {
   "query":{
      "bool":{
        "must": [
          {
            "match": {"etats.etat": "ROUTEE"}
          }
        ],
        "filter":[
          {"range" : {"etats.date" : {"gte" : "2022-11-09T00:00:00.000+0100","lt" : "2022-11-09T23:59:59.000+0100"}}}
        ]
      }
      
   }
 }
```

But the 2 documents are selected.

Thank you for your response

I would like to have only the first document

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to define etats as a nested field. Elastic search flattens arrays  so relation ship between objects in array is lost. Nested field preserves each object in an array as a separate document . You can read about nested field [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

Once mapping is changed you can use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to get data

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "etats",
      "inner_hits": {} --> it will return matched inner documents.
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter":[
             {"range" : {"etats.date" : {"gte" : "2022-11-09T00:00:00.000+0100","lt" : "2022-11-09T23:59:59.000+0100"}}}],
          ],
          "must": [
           {
            "match": {"etats.etat": "ROUTEE"}
           }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```